# Relationship between gradient clipping and gradient accumulation

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I try to do gradient accumulation (from [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#gradient-accumulation)) for RNN model, so I also need to clip gradient. For example, I decided to use gradient norm threshold = 1.

Should I increase my max_norm (threshold = 1) corresponding to how many iters I accumulate (4)?

```
loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
num_batches = 1
running_loss = 0.0
iters_to_accumulate = 4
scaler = GradScaler()

model.train()
for batch in tqdm(train_generator, desc='Training'):
        with autocast(device_type=device.type, dtype=torch.float16):
            output = torch.flatten(model(batch['features'], batch['category'])).to(device)
            batch_loss = loss_function(output, batch['label'].float())
            batch_loss = batch_loss / iters_to_accumulate

        scaler.scale(batch_loss).backward()

        if (num_batches) % iters_to_accumulate == 0:
            scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.)
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

        num_batches += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the gradient clipping value to account for gradient accumulation. In gradient accumulation, the gradients are additive, but this is corrected for by scaling the loss (`batch_loss = batch_loss / iters_to_accumulate`). Loss scaling ensures that the combined gradient accumulated over `n` batches has the same magnitude as the gradient from a single large batch.